# Has anyone seen Squish that you must re-record after moving?

Tags: python, qt, squish

I'm using a combination of Python and Squish for Qt to write tests on a Qt GUI, but I have noticed when I copy and paste tests from a suite I have and move them to another suite or computer with Squish the file will run, but when it runs anytime it sees an object name it does not recognize it and throws an exception. Most of the time I use the picker tool to go get the object name and place it where the old object name was and it works (I might add that the object names haven't changed I'm literally copying and pasting a string over THE SAME EXACT string). I must be doing something wrong. Has anyone seen this or have a way of resolving the issue so I don't have to re-record?

Answer (score 3):

> ... but I have noticed when I copy and paste tests from a suite
>   I have and move them to another suite or computer with Squish the file
>   will run, but when it runs anytime it sees an object name it does not
>   recognize it and throws an exception ...

For your test script, Squish creates this suite folder you mention.
Inside this folder, you also have besides the *test.py* file, a *object.map* file (in which squish stores all the objects that you use inside the test).
Also, besides those 2 files you have a *suite.conf* file.

Instead of copy/paste your test script file, you could move the suite folder on the other computer, and there open it in SquishIDE. Or along with the test script, copy also the *object.map* file.

Comment: Object map is the most important part. You can share it among suites by selecting the shared file in the suite settings as long as you work with the same AUT.

Answer (score 0):

@EugenG is right, the object map contains the mapping from symbolic name (`:OK_Button`) to real name (`{type='Button' text='OK'}`) and thus you need to copy the respective entries to the object map of the new test suite, or simply "teach" them in the fly with Squish's Object Name Found handling while executing the test script. To speed this up, Squish version 6.4+ will support reducing the default timeout for waitForObject() & co via testSettings.waitForObjectTimeout.

And @EugenG is also right about the possibility to [share an object map between test suites](https://kb.froglogic.com/display/KB/Sharing+an+Object+Map+across+test+suites).

Answer (score 0):

Restart the squish IDE after you moved your test suite.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).